# dynamically show and hide fields based on select box selection for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to dynamically show and hide the specific input fields based on the selection made. I tried it with a for loop but its showing the two input at a time which i don't want. I want it to show for example: when i select Performer 1 it show show Performer1f and Performer1l but hide the others. I know i could hard code it to show and hide but its too length when you have around 100 fields to show and hide based on the selection.

Much help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```js
function perfChange() {

  $('.myselectperf option').each(function(){

   var size=$('#myselectperf option').length;

  // as a comma separated string

   for (z=1; z<=size; z++){
    if (this.value == "Performer "+z+"") {
      //$(".myselectperf option[value='Pianoforte']").add();
      //$(".myselectperf option[value='Performer "+z+"']").remove();
       //$('#mul_cat').value="testing";
     $("#Performer"+z+"f").show();
     $("#Performer"+z+"l").show();
     $("#performerLabel").show();
    }
    else {
      $("#Performer"+z+"f").hide();
     $("#Performer"+z+"l").hide();
     $("#performerLabel").hide();

    }

  }

  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="myselect" id="myselect" onChange="perfChange();"  >
  <option value="" selected>-Select-</option>
  <option value="Performer 1" >Performer 1</option>
  <option value="Performer 2" >Performer 2</option>
  <option value="Performer 3" >Performer 3</option>
  <option value="Performer 4" >Performer 4</option>
  <option value="Performer 5" >Performer 5</option>
  </select>

<input type="text" id="Performer1f" style="display: none; width: 100%;" name='entryname1f[]' placeholder="Performer 1 First Name " />

<input type="text" id="Performer2f" style="display: none; width: 100%;" name='entryname1f[]' placeholder="Performer 2 First Name "/>

<input type="text" id="Performer3f" style="display: none; width: 100%;" name='entryname1f[] ' placeholder="Performer 3 First Name "/>

<input type="text" id="Performer4f" style="display: none; width: 100%;" name='entryname1f[]' placeholder="Performer 4 First Name "/>

<input type="text" id="Performer5f" style="display: none; width: 100%;" name='entryname1f[]' placeholder="Performer 5 First Name "/>



<input type="text" id="Performer1l" style="display: none; width: 100%;" name='entryname1l[]' placeholder="Performer 1 Last Name " />

<input type="text" id="Performer2l" style="display: none; width: 100%;" name='entryname1l[]' placeholder="Performer 2 Last Name "/>

<input type="text" id="Performer3l" style="display: none; width: 100%;" name='entryname1l[] ' placeholder="Performer 3 Last Name "/>

<input type="text" id="Performer4l" style="display: none; width: 100%;" name='entryname1l[]' placeholder="Performer 4 Last Name "/>

<input type="text" id="Performer5l" style="display: none; width: 100%;" name='entryname1l[]' placeholder="Performer 5 Last Name "/>
```

Comment: please make clearer which fields should be shown and hidden based on the selection.

Comment: it's in the description "for example: when i select Performer 1 from the selectbox it should show Performer1f and Performer1l from the input fields but hide the others. I know i could hard code it to show and hide but its too length when you have around 100 fields to show and hide based on the selection."

Comment: Sorry I missed that, apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution I have come up with.

- Used `$('#myselect').on('change'...)` to bind a change event
  to the `select`.
- Hid all the other elements to not stack-up other `elements` from
  the previous selection.
- Later, used `e.target.value` to get the value of the `option`.
- Used that value to compare against `id` of the `inputs`. [Caret (`^`) matches the beginning of the id]
- Using `.show()` we can display hidden items in `jQuery`.

**Code:**

---

```js
$('#myselect').on('change', e => {
  // Hide all input with type `text` upon change
  // You can edit this code to match an ID or a Class instead
  $('input[type="text"]').hide();
  
  // Retrieved value of the `option`
  let value = e.target.value;
  
  // Select all elements that `start` with the id value
  let foundInputs = $(`input[id^="${value}"]`);
  
  // Show the selected inputs
  foundInputs.show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="myselect" id="myselect">
  <option value="" selected>-Select-</option>
  <option value="Performer1">Performer 1</option>
  <option value="Performer2">Performer 2</option>
  <option value="Performer3">Performer 3</option>
  <option value="Performer4">Performer 4</option>
  <option value="Performer5">Performer 5</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="Performer1f" style="display: none; width: 100%;" name='entryname1f[]' placeholder="Performer 1 First Name " />

<input type="text" id="Performer2f" style="display: none; width: 100%;" name='entryname1f[]' placeholder="Performer 2 First Name " />

<input type="text" id="Performer3f" style="display: none; width: 100%;" name='entryname1f[] ' placeholder="Performer 3 First Name " />

<input type="text" id="Performer4f" style="display: none; width: 100%;" name='entryname1f[]' placeholder="Performer 4 First Name " />

<input type="text" id="Performer5f" style="display: none; width: 100%;" name='entryname1f[]' placeholder="Performer 5 First Name " />

<input type="text" id="Performer1l" style="display: none; width: 100%;" name='entryname1l[]' placeholder="Performer 1 Last Name " />

<input type="text" id="Performer2l" style="display: none; width: 100%;" name='entryname1l[]' placeholder="Performer 2 Last Name " />

<input type="text" id="Performer3l" style="display: none; width: 100%;" name='entryname1l[] ' placeholder="Performer 3 Last Name " />

<input type="text" id="Performer4l" style="display: none; width: 100%;" name='entryname1l[]' placeholder="Performer 4 Last Name " />

<input type="text" id="Performer5l" style="display: none; width: 100%;" name='entryname1l[]' placeholder="Performer 5 Last Name " />
```

Comment: Glad to be of any help. :) Select best answer if you have everything working.

Comment: But remember to give other folks a chance to come up with something better, as acceptance of an answer does seem to dissuade others from putting in effort to offer an alternative.

Comment: I'm completely aware of that. Hence I didn't tell him to select my answer as the best answer. Just mentioned it to not keep this post hanging.

Comment: when it reach 10 performers it shows it too it seems the problem is with the place holder

Comment: The problem is in what way you want to select the `input`. Like I mentioned, instead of `placeholder`, you may use `id` or `class` or `data` attributes, it really doesn't matter. Or simply remove spaces from your values in your `options` and compare against something else.

Comment: ok noted. but i would really like to let it stay how it is and have it working.

Comment: Best case scenario is to set your `option` values e.g. `Performer1` and use this instead: `  let foundInputs = $(`input[id^="${value}"]`);`. Which will match both `Performer1f` & `Performer1l`. I'll make the edit now.

Answer (score 1):

See this code for better understanding:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="myselect" id="myselect" onChange="perfChange(this.value);"  >
  <option value="" selected>-Select-</option>
  <option value="1" >Performer 1</option>
  <option value="2" >Performer 2</option>
  <option value="3" >Performer 3</option>
  <option value="4" >Performer 4</option>
  <option value="5" >Performer 5</option>
  </select>

<input class="hideinput" type="text" id="Performer1f" style="display: none; width: 100%;" name='entryname1f[]' placeholder="Performer 1 First Name " />

<input class="hideinput" type="text" id="Performer2f" style="display: none; width: 100%;" name='entryname1f[]' placeholder="Performer 2 First Name "/>

<input class="hideinput" type="text" id="Performer3f" style="display: none; width: 100%;" name='entryname1f[] ' placeholder="Performer 3 First Name "/>

<input class="hideinput" type="text" id="Performer4f" style="display: none; width: 100%;" name='entryname1f[]' placeholder="Performer 4 First Name "/>

<input class="hideinput" type="text" id="Performer5f" style="display: none; width: 100%;" name='entryname1f[]' placeholder="Performer 5 First Name "/>



<input class="hideinput" type="text" id="Performer1l" style="display: none; width: 100%;" name='entryname1l[]' placeholder="Performer 1 Last Name " />

<input class="hideinput" type="text" id="Performer2l" style="display: none; width: 100%;" name='entryname1l[]' placeholder="Performer 2 Last Name "/>

<input class="hideinput" type="text" id="Performer3l" style="display: none; width: 100%;" name='entryname1l[] ' placeholder="Performer 3 Last Name "/>

<input class="hideinput" type="text" id="Performer4l" style="display: none; width: 100%;" name='entryname1l[]' placeholder="Performer 4 Last Name "/>

<input class="hideinput" type="text" id="Performer5l" style="display: none; width: 100%;" name='entryname1l[]' placeholder="Performer 5 Last Name "/>


<script>
function perfChange(display_id = 0) {
 var make_id_1 = "#Performer"+display_id+"f";
  var make_id_2 = "#Performer"+display_id+"l";
  $(".hideinput").hide();
  $(make_id_1).show();
  $(make_id_2).show();
}
</script>
```

Steps to understand:

1. First I am passing a value of the option to perfChange function
2. In perfChange function now I am creating the id by using this id
3. After that, I have added all the inputs to a class `hideinput`.
4. Now By using this class, I am hiding all the inputs after that I am only trying to show those inputs which need to show

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just hide them all and show the selected.

```
for (z=1; z<=size; z++){
   $("#Performer"+z+"f").hide();
   $("#Performer"+z+"l").hide();
  }
$("#"+this.value+"f").show();
$("#"+this.value+"l").show();
```

Comment: explain more please. show the entire code for the jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your select box values as performer_1,performer_2 and so on. and pass this value to perfchange(this.value). and then split it from _ and show your div as follow.

```js
function perfChange(val) {
var div=val.split('_');
$("#Performer"+div[1]+"f").show();
$("#Performer"+div[1]+"l").show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="myselect" id="myselect" onChange="perfChange(this.value);"  >
  <option value="" selected>-Select-</option>
  <option value="Performer_1" >Performer 1</option>
  <option value="Performer_2" >Performer 2</option>
  <option value="Performer_3" >Performer 3</option>
  <option value="Performer_4" >Performer 4</option>
  <option value="Performer_5" >Performer 5</option>
  </select>

<input type="text" id="Performer1f" style="display: none; width: 100%;" name='entryname1f[]' placeholder="Performer 1 First Name " />

<input type="text" id="Performer2f" style="display: none; width: 100%;" name='entryname1f[]' placeholder="Performer 2 First Name "/>

<input type="text" id="Performer3f" style="display: none; width: 100%;" name='entryname1f[] ' placeholder="Performer 3 First Name "/>

<input type="text" id="Performer4f" style="display: none; width: 100%;" name='entryname1f[]' placeholder="Performer 4 First Name "/>

<input type="text" id="Performer5f" style="display: none; width: 100%;" name='entryname1f[]' placeholder="Performer 5 First Name "/>



<input type="text" id="Performer1l" style="display: none; width: 100%;" name='entryname1l[]' placeholder="Performer 1 Last Name " />

<input type="text" id="Performer2l" style="display: none; width: 100%;" name='entryname1l[]' placeholder="Performer 2 Last Name "/>

<input type="text" id="Performer3l" style="display: none; width: 100%;" name='entryname1l[] ' placeholder="Performer 3 Last Name "/>

<input type="text" id="Performer4l" style="display: none; width: 100%;" name='entryname1l[]' placeholder="Performer 4 Last Name "/>

<input type="text" id="Performer5l" style="display: none; width: 100%;" name='entryname1l[]' placeholder="Performer 5 Last Name "/>
```