# Hide a field based on populated value from database php

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I would like to hide input field based on dropdown value. So two values are auto populated from database stone1 and stone 2
so if stone1 is pupated I want karat to be hidden and if stone 2 then carat and if any more values
populated both should be hidden

```
<label for="form" class="control-label">=Service</label>
<select  id="form1" class="custom-select custom-select-sm select2" >
   <option selected="" disabled>Select services First</option>
   <?php
      ?>
   <!-- <option value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" ><?php echo $name ?></option> -->
   <?php endwhile; ?>
   <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="form-group ctd" data-cid="ctd">
         <label for="ctd">stone1</label>
<select class="form-control" id="ctd" name="ctd">
<option>24</option>
<option>22</option>
<option>20</option>
<option>18</option>
<option>16</option>
<option>14</option>
</select>
</div>  
</div> 
<div class="col-md-2">
   <div class="form-group ctg" data-cid="ctg">
      <label for="ctg">stone2</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="ctg" name="ctg">
         <option>24</option>
         <option>22</option>
         <option>20</option>
         <option>18</option>
         <option>16</option>
         <option>14</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

So two values are auto-populated from database stone1 and stone 2 so if stone1 is populated I want karat to be hidden and if stone 2 then carat and if any more values populated both should be hidden

I tried this code but it hides only one and does not work at all

```
<script>    
  var form1 = jQuery('#form1');
  var select = this.value;
  form_id.change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == 'stone1') {
      $('.ctd').show();             
    } else {
      $('.ctg').hide(); 
    }               
  });       
           
</script>
```

Comment: Is `$(this).val() == 'stone1'` ever true? Should be able to narrow down what the issue is. "Does not work" is vague.

Comment: my mistake i corrected it....

Comment: I still use `console.log()` to debug JS like this. I'd set up a handler on the select's change event instead of the form. Get to where you are sure you are handling the event and getting the selected value, go from there.

Comment: no errors shown

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dynamically show and hide fields based on select box selection for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51210764/dynamically-show-and-hide-fields-based-on-select-box-selection-for-loop) or [Displaying or hiding multiple fields based on selection dropdown - jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57524251/displaying-or-hiding-multiple-fields-based-on-selection-dropdown-jquery)

Comment: i tried that too

Comment: What is `this.value`?

Comment: revise your code, your opening and closing tags are not consistent

Comment: Ok revised my code its woking now.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
     (function ($) {
 
     $(function () {
        var form1 = jQuery('#form1');
   var select = this.value;
         $('#form1').change(function(){
             if( $(this).val()==="1" ){
                 $("#ctd").show()
                $("#ctg").hide()
                $('label[for="ctg"]').hide();
                $('label[for="ctd"]').show();
             } else {
                $("#ctg").show()
                 $("#ctd").hide()
                $('label[for="ctd"]').hide();
                $('label[for="ctg"]').show();
             }
         });
 
 
         $('#form1').trigger("change");
     });
 
 }(jQuery));
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).